# Help with pgf plot

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to create a plot using pgfplot tool for latex. I want to plot $z=\sin(x)\sin(y)$ to create a plot that looks like [image]
So am am just imitating the code provided in the picture with the preamble mentioned.

```
    \begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot3[surf,domainin=0:360, sample=40, shader=none] 
    {sin(x)*sin(y)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
```

But I am getting [image: My result]. I know its a problem with scaling but I tried to include `ymin, ymax, xmin, xmax` values with even disastrous results. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You have `domainin` instead of `domain`.

Comment: You should correct the typos and rerun. It works for me. (Except for the `shader=none`)

Comment: OHHHHHHHHHHHHH sorry yes it's just that I am getting the desired one now. I am sorry for the whole thing, I have been pulling my hairs for last few hours :(

Comment: You did not wonder what the `Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/domainin', to which you passed '0:360', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.` could mean? ;-)

Comment: That's true there were a lot of hbox fill comments in the dialogue box and I did not look for anything new! I did not extract this particular frame and ran in a different file which would have probably attracted my attention to this!

Comment: Do not mistake this, it is meant to be constructive: This is exactly why we often ask people to put a MWE when posting a question. In many cases, the process of creating a MWE already solves the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works (you had `domainin` and it's `domain`; you had `sample` and it's `samples`,  and I suppressed the `shader`):

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot3[surf,domain=0:360, samples=40] 
    {sin(x)*sin(y)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. Is there a way to rotate the plot in a small animation to show the maximums and minimums for the viewers in here?

Comment: @baharampuri You're welcome. That's a completely different issue. Consider opening a fresh new question.

Comment: Gladly, that's the cue I was looking for!